# Erro ao salvar uma imagem obtida pelo Opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Diretório onde eu preciso salvar

```
  Banco-de-Faces\nome
```

Diretório onde ele está salvando:

```
  Banco-de-Faces
```

Meu código:

```
  cv2.imwrite("Banco-de-Faces\\" + nome + str(framesObtidos) + ".png", imagemRosto)
```

O meu programa cria uma pasta com o nome digitado, eu tenho que gravar essas imagens dentro dessa pasta, e o nome de cada imagem vai se chamar `NomeDigitado + (numero do frame).png`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você não está utilizando um separador entre o nome do diretório e o nome do arquivo. O que seu código faz, é juntar o `nome` com o `framesObtidos` para formar um só nome de arquivo. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
dir1 = "Dir1/"
dir2 = "Dir2"
arquivo = "arquivo.png"
print(dir1 + dir2 + arquivo)   # Saída: Dir1/Dir2arquivo.png
```

Para corrigir esse problema basta adicionar `"\\"` entre `nome` e `framesObtidos` dessa forma:

```
cv2.imwrite("Banco-de-Faces\\" + nome + "\\" + str(framesObtidos) + ".png", imagemRosto)
```

Uma melhoria que você pode fazer no seu código é utilizar a função `os.path.join` para unir os diretórios com o nome de arquivo utilizando um separador adequado para o seu sistema operacional. Dessa forma, você evita conflitos e também deixa o código mais organizado e bonito. Exemplo:

```
filename = os.path.join("Banco-de-Faces", nome, str(framesObtidos) + ".png")
cv2.imwrite(filename, imagemRosto)
```